# Find multiple links on the same line and return paths

Tags: python, find

I would like to find multiple links on the same line from an HTML page or a text file and return paths.
For the moment, I manage to find the first link on the line but when I have two links on the same line, it doesn't work and I can't find a solution so I'd like some help.

```
def get_href(line) : 
    x = line.find('href=')
    if x < 0 : return 
    ref = line[x+6:].split('"')[0] 
    if ref.startswith('http:') : return ref 

hrefs = []
flux = urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
for line in flux : hrefs.append(get_href(line))
```

Comment: show the `line` content

Comment: How about splitting `ligne` on `"href"`?

Comment: The `line` content is from any website or page. I get the string line per line.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and I think it works :

```
def get_href(line) : 
    tab = []
    link = []
    x = line.find('href=')
    if x < 0: pass
    else :
        tab = line.split('"')
        for ref in tab:
            if ref.startswith('http:') or ref.startswith('https:') : link.append(ref)
        print link
```